# Appending relation to ActiveRecord object using Ruby send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to dynamically append a relational object to it's associated object using the `send` method. For example:

```
car = Car.first
tire = Tire.first
car.send('tires<<', tire)
```

But I always get method undefined. I realize in this simple example it's not necessary to use `send`, but in my case it is. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `tires<<` method, there is a `<<` method defined on object returned by `tires`. Try:

```
car.send('tires') << tire
```